# Enumeration function Argument

Tags: python

Python enumeration function enumerate takes one argument ***start***. 
What is the use of this argument ? 
If i write some code using this argument it shifts only index e.g.

```
>>a=[2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>for index,value in enumerate(a,start=2):
 ...    print index,value
 ...    
 **2 2**
 3 3
 4 4
 5 5
 6 6
 7 7
 8 8
```

So index is changed to 2 ,Not Value.Value is still started from first element. Why this is so ? In place of this functionality ,It could be better if value is started from that index rather than starting element.
What was the thinking behind the implementation of this ?

Comment: You'll find the proper documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). `enumerate` associates an index with an iterable. The `start` element just changes the index associated with the first element of the iterable. If you want to start your enumeration at index 2, then use the slicing `enumerate(a[2:])`.

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate()` associates a sequence of integers with an iterable, i.e. it enumerates the items of the sequence. Its argument `start` is not meant to affect the starting position within the iterable, just the initial value from which to start counting.

One use is to start the enumeration from 1 instead of 0, e.g. if you wanted to number the lines in a file:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        print(line_number, line)
```

This outputs the line numbers starting from 1, which is where most users would expect line numbering to begin.

If you want to skip the first *n* items in a sequence you can just slice it:

```
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
n = 2
for index, value in enumerate(a[n:]):
    print index, value
```

outputs

```
0 4
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

but you might like to start the enumeration from 3 as well:

```
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
n = 2
for index, value in enumerate(a[n:], n+1):
    print index, value
```

which would output

```
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people - most I suppose - aren't used to an enumerated list starting at zero. At the very least, this makes it easy to format the output so the enumeration starts at one, e.g.

```
a = ['Fred', 'Ted', 'Bob', 'Alice']
for index, value in enumerate(a, start=1):
    print index, value
```

will print out:

```
1 Fred
2 Ted
3 Bob
4 Alice
```

Without the `start=1` parameter, `enumerate(a)` would print

```
0 Fred
1 Ted
2 Bob
3 Alice
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate